# Rails 4 How to User Redis Counters with hincrby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, counter, increment

I am new to Redis and would like to use redis to increment counters with

```
hincrby
```

User model has 3 has_many associations to keep track with the counters.

```
User has_many :alerts
User has_many :messages
User has_many :notifications
```

Each time I want to increase the counter.

```
$redis.hincrby("myhash", value, 1)
```

It is not clear how to use it.

1. Have a user:#{user_id} hash and increment each key

   ```
   $redis.hincrby("user:#{user_id}", "alerts", 1)
   $redis.hincrby("user:#{user_id}", "messages", 1)
   $redis.hincrby("user:#{user_id}", "notifications", 1)
   ```
2. Have 3 hashes alerts, messages, notifications and increase the user_id key

   ```
   $redis.hincrby("alert", user_id, 1)
   $redis.hincrby("messages", user_id, 1)
   $redis.hincrby("notifications", user_id, 1)
   ```

In the first scenario, if n is the number of users, there are n hashes with 3 keys-value pairs at the root level whereas in the second scenario there are 3 hashes at the root level with n key-value pairs.

Any insights on the different approaches?

Comment: You have to evaluate which is better depending on how are you going to access the data. i.e. do you need to retrieve all the counters for a user? Do you need to retrieve all the users for a counter?

Comment: Need to retrieve all the counters for a user

Comment: In that case I would recommend your first approach